Ошибка при установке Local Bot Server от Телеграмма (cmake, vcpkg)
Прошу прощения за возможную глупость, я начинающий)
Я хотел сделать телеграмм бота на aiogram, в функционал которого входила бы отправка видео >50МБ (лимит для ботов). Чтобы преодолеть этот лимит по советам из инета я решил накатить Local Bot Server на свой проект. Скачал по ссылке из генератора инструкций для Windows 10: GIT,Cmake, Visual Studio с поддержкой C++ и также установил Powershell 7 версии. Выполнение данных команд, созданных инструкцией для установления сервера проходило успешно:
git clone --recursive https://github.com/tdlib/telegram-bot-api.git
cd telegram-bot-api
git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg.git
cd vcpkg
./bootstrap-vcpkg.bat

Однако во время исполнения в консоли powershell конкретной строки:  ./vcpkg.exe install gperf:x64-windows openssl:x64-windows zlib:x64-windows  - я получаю ошибку. Мой ввод и вывод консоли:
PS C:\Users\Лазарь Чернецов\Desktop\ПРОЕКТ 10 КЛАСС ТГ БОТ\telegram-bot-api\vcpkg> ./vcpkg.exe install gperf:x64-windows openssl:x64-windows zlib:x64-windows
Computing installation plan...
The following packages will be built and installed:
    gperf:x64-windows@3.1#6
    openssl:x64-windows@3.3.2#1
  * vcpkg-cmake-get-vars:x64-windows@2024-09-22
    zlib:x64-windows@1.3.1
Additional packages (*) will be modified to complete this operation.
Detecting compiler hash for triplet x64-windows...
Compiler found: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.41.34120/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
Restored 0 package(s) from C:\Users\Лазарь Чернецов\AppData\Local\vcpkg\archives in 759 us. Use --debug to see more details.
Installing 1/4 gperf:x64-windows@3.1#6...
Building gperf:x64-windows@3.1#6...
-- Downloading http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/gperf/gperf-3.1.tar.gz -> gperf-3.1.tar.gz...

CMake Error at scripts/cmake/vcpkg_download_distfile.cmake:32 (message):

      Failed to download file with error: no such file or directory
      If you are using a proxy, please check your proxy setting. Possible causes are:

      1. You are actually using an HTTP proxy, but setting HTTPS_PROXY variable
         to `https://address:port`. This is not correct, because `https://` prefix
         claims the proxy is an HTTPS proxy, while your proxy (v2ray, shadowsocksr
         , etc..) is an HTTP proxy. Try setting `http://address:port` to both
         HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY instead.

      2. If you are using Windows, vcpkg will automatically use your Windows IE Proxy Settings
         set by your proxy software. See https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg-tool/pull/77
         The value set by your proxy might be wrong, or have same `https://` prefix issue.

      3. Your proxy's remote server is out of service.

      If you've tried directly download the link, and believe this is not a temporary
      download server failure, please submit an issue at https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg/issues
      to report this upstream download server failure.


Call Stack (most recent call first):
  scripts/cmake/vcpkg_download_distfile.cmake:270 (z_vcpkg_download_distfile_show_proxy_and_fail)
  ports/gperf/portfile.cmake:3 (vcpkg_download_distfile)
  scripts/ports.cmake:192 (include)


error: building gperf:x64-windows failed with: BUILD_FAILED
See https://learn.microsoft.com/vcpkg/troubleshoot/build-failures?WT.mc_id=vcpkg_inproduct_cli for more information.
Elapsed time to handle gperf:x64-windows: 121 ms
Please ensure you're using the latest port files with `git pull` and `vcpkg update`.
Then check for known issues at:
  https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+in%3Atitle+gperf
You can submit a new issue at:
  https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/new?title=[gperf]+Build+error+on+x64-windows&body=Copy+issue+body+from+C%3A%2FUsers%2F%D0%9B%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C%20%D0%A7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%86%D0%BE%D0%B2%2FDesktop%2F%D0%9F%D0%A0%D0%9E%D0%95%D0%9A%D0%A2%2010%20%D0%9A%D0%9B%D0%90%D0%A1%D0%A1%20%D0%A2%D0%93%20%D0%91%D0%9E%D0%A2%2Ftelegram-bot-api%2Fvcpkg%2Finstalled%2Fvcpkg%2Fissue_body.md


При помощи команды git pull я удостоверился в наличии последней версии git. Однако при проверке vcpkg командой vcpkg update - я получил еще одну ошибку, которая возможно связана с главной проблемой:
vcpkg: The term 'vcpkg' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Suggestion [3,General]: The command "vcpkg" was not found, but does exist in the current location.
PowerShell does not load commands from the current location by default (see ''Get-Help about_Command_Precedence'').

Так же искал на других форумах решение этой проблемы, но не нашел подходящих вариантов, дающих ответов.
Возможно кто-то уже работал с Local Bot сервером и, я очень надеюсь, сможет мне подсказать/помочь.
Если будут необходимы подробности - постараюсь их дать.
Заранее Благодарю!

Проблему решил! Дело оказалось в русских буквах (и возможно пробелах) на пути к папке, в которую я пытался установить сервер. Поместив папку в новое место, путь к которому состоял из латиницы без пробелов - все скачалось успешно.
